# Cannot store value into database

Tags: php, mysql

when i submit the form..
the form display the 'error' msg that mean the query does'nt work..
i've compare the code with the other code and it seem similar...
i dont know what to do with this..
please guys...
help me...

(here's is the form code)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['bookno']))
        $bookingno = $_GET['bookno'];
    elseif(isset($_POST['bookno']))
        $bookingno = $_POST['bookno'];
    else
        $bookingno = "";

    $db = mysql_connect('localhost','root') 
    or die ("unable to connect");
    mysql_select_db('fyp',$db) or die ("able to select");

$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM `booking` "
                    . " WHERE `bookingno`='".trim($bookingno)."'";

     $result = mysql_query($sql_select) or die ("Query failed!");
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     extract($row);

 ?>
    <form method ="post" action="appbooking.php">
<font face= "arial" size="2" font color="black">
<center>
<table width="800" height="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="28" colspan="8" valign="middle" bgcolor="#0A25E9"><center>
      <font color="white" size="3" face="Times New Roman" font="font"><b>BOOKING DETAIL</b></font>
    </center>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="129" align="left" ><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">Booking No</font></td>
    <td width="291"><input name="bookingno" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['bookingno']; ?>" size="30" ></td>
    <td width="94" align="left" ><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">User ID</font></td>
    <td width="270"><input name="username" type="text" id="username" value= "<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" size="30" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="129" align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000"> Name</font></td>
    <td width="291"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value= "<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"size="45" ></td>
    <td width="94" align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">Department</font></td>
    <td><input name="department" type="text" id="department" value= "<?php echo $row['department']; ?>" size="45" >
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="129" align="left" ><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">Required Date</font></td>
    <td width="291"><input name="u_g_date" type="text" id="g_date" value= "<?php echo $row['g_date']; ?>" size="30" ></td>
    <td width="94" align="left" ><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">Required Time</font></td>
    <td><input name="g_time" type="text" id="g_time" value= "<?php echo $row['g_time']; ?>" size="30" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="129" align="left" ><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">Return Date</font></td>
    <td width="291"><input name="u_r_date" type="text" id="r_date" value= "<?php echo $row['r_date']; ?>" size="30" ></td>
    <td width="94" align="left" ><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">Return Time</font></td>
    <td><input name="r_time" type="text" id="r_time" value= "<?php echo $row['r_time']; ?>" size="30" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="129" align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">Destination</font></td>
    <td width="291"><input name="u_destination" type="text" id="destination" value= "<?php echo $row['destination']; ?>" size="45" ></td>
    <td width="94" align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">Num Of Passengger</font></td>
    <td><input name="pass_num" type="text" id="pass_num" value= "<?php echo $row['pass_num']; ?>" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="129" align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2" font color="#000000">Purpose Of Trip</font></td>
    <td width="291"><textarea name="trip_purpose" rows="3" cols="40 " >
           <?php echo $row['trip_purpose']; ?>
           </textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <td><p>&nbsp;</p>
  <tr>
   <tr>
        <td height="28" colspan="8" valign="middle" bgcolor="#0A25E9">
        &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;    &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;    &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;    &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;    

        <font color="white" size="3" face="Times New Roman"     font="font"><b>APPROVE</b></font>
        &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;    &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;    &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;


        <font color="white" size="3" face="Times New Roman"     font="font"><b>REJECT</b></font>
</td>

  </tr>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <?php
     $db = mysql_connect('localhost','root') 
     or die ("unable to connect");
    mysql_select_db('fyp',$db) or die ("able to select");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE v_status='READY'";

     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query failed!");  
 ?>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Registration Number 
    <td><select name="regno">
            <option value="" selected>--Registration No--</option>
            <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['regno']; ?>"><?php echo $row['regno']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select></td>
    <td>Reason</td>
  <td><textarea name="reason" rows="3" cols="50 "value = ""></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
     $db = mysql_connect('localhost','root') 
     or die ("unable to connect");
    mysql_select_db('fyp',$db) or die ("able to select");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM driver WHERE d_status='READY'";

     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query failed!");  
 ?>
  <tr>
    <td>Driver</td>
    <td><select id = "d_name" name="u_d_name">
      <option value="" selected>--Driver Name--</option>
      <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['d_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['d_name']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<?php                    
      mysql_close($db);
?>

</table>

(here's the code for the addprocessor)
<?php
   $db = mysql_connect('localhost','root') 
     or die ("unable to connect");
     mysql_select_db('fyp',$db)
     or die ("able to select");

    $bookingno=$_POST['bookingno'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $department=$_POST['department'];
    $g_date=$_POST['g_date'];
    $r_date=$_POST['r_date'];
    $r_time=$_POST['r_time'];
    $destination=$_POST['destination'];
    $pass_num=$_POST['pass_num'];
    $trip_purpose=$_POST['trip_purpose'];
    $regno=$_POST['regno'];
    $d_name=$_POST['d_name'];
    $reason=$_POST['reason'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO usage VALUES('$bookingno','$username','$name','$department', '$g_date', '$g_time', '$r_date', '$r_time', '$destination', '$pass_num', '$trip_purpose', '$regno', '$d_name', '$reason')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("error!");
//$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ($query);

echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Booking No : </b>".$bookingno."</font>"."<br>";  
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Applicant's ID : </b>".$username."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Applicant's Name : </b>".$name."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Department : </b>".$department."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Required Date : </b>".$g_date."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Required Time: </b>".$g_time."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Return Date : </b>".$r_date."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Return Time : </b>".$r_time."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Destinantion : </b>".$destination."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Number Of Passenger : </b>".$pass_num."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Trip Purpose : </b>".$trip_purpose."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Registration Number : </b>".$regno."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Driver Name : </b>".$d_name."</font>"."<br>";
echo "<font face = arial size= 3><b>Reject Reason : </b>".$reason."</font>"."<br>";


mysql_close($db);

echo "<font face = arial size= 4>You have sucessfully record booking details to the database.</font>";  

?>
```

Comment: @ejah85: Do you realize that your code looks like a mess? Would you mind to edit your question, reformat code, select it and press Ctrl+K to display it as code and check preview if it helped?

Comment: Red Alert: You are using POST parameters literally in the query. Don't do that, not even at home; bad habits are hard to unlearn. Use mysql_real_escape_string or something like that to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Looks like `extraneon` did that formatting for you. Please check your edited question to find out why it looks better now...

Comment: thanks peter for that....trutly i doesnt know how to paste it as a code..thanks :-)

Comment: thanks everybody...i feel like i'am stupid idiot..im newbie in php and also new member in this forum...

Comment: Don't feel like that. We all started from the very similar code or even worst :) In a weeks you will do much better. Especially if you stuck with SO :)

Comment: thanks col...i never develop any system using php before this...but know i must develop a system that manage the booking and manage vehicle...and it's my final year project and very important time for my graduate condiotion :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$bookingno=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bookingno']);
```

and so on

Note that

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error (mysql_error().' in '.$sql);
```

call would be much more informative in case of error

Comment: i've used the code and the error the system cannot detect the time in the time field..thans col..ur code are great :-)

Comment: note that mysql_real_escape_string() function must be applied to the **every** variable you put into query, which you enclose in quoptes. $bookingno in your SELECT query too. I's 2 parts of one mechanism - quotes and mysql_real_escape_string(), both must be used always together, they are useless alone. so, if you have something like `'$var'` in your query, it must be preceeded by mysql_real_escape_string($var); no exceptions

Comment: thanks col :-)
u means that $bookingno=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bookingno']);
should be $bookingno=mysql_real_escape_string($bookingno);?

Comment: what does it say about error? 
You have unusual structure of your script. It can be problem too. I'd suggest to separate form processing from the other code. 
make script `action.php` and make it `action=action.php` in the form

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
```

It should give you a better error message.

Answer (score 1):

You did'not specify a list of column names. Do you provide values for every column in the table?